# How early can I check-in at KEF airport in Iceland?

Tags: check-in, kef

I am going to be traveling and doing a stopover in Iceland, but I am not planning on staying at a hotel. How early can I check in if my flight is at 7am?

Comment: Note that just because you can check in doesn't nessacerally mean you can drop baggage.

Comment: Do you really mean check-in, or are you asking at what time you can show up at the airport to get XXX accomplished ? Online check in is almost always available 23-24 hours before departure.

Answer (score 1):

Checkin times are set by the airline, not the airport.

Most airlines have a 24-hour policy for checkin, but some have different periods.  Check your airline's website to find out their checkin period.

Comment: I believe some airlines (probably mostly LCCs?) have much much shorter periods. IIRC EasyJet has a 2 or 3 hour limit.

Comment: @jcaron That's entirely possible; I tend to avoid the ULCCs :).  I've flown Air Canada, WestJet, United, British Airways, and the now-defunct Canadian and Continental, and they all had checkin at T-24 hours.

Comment: @Abigail, by check-in I actually meant the baggage drop. Not 100% sure it was Easyjet, but it happened to be once at Gatwick, I had to wait for half an hour on the side before I could drop my bags. The Easyjet online check-in can actually be done weeks before, basically as soon as you have booked your ticket.

Answer (score 1):

The [website of the airport](https://www.kefairport.is/English/At-the-Airport/Before-Departure/) will tell you: it's 2.5 to 3 hours before the flight, depending on the airline. This is of course for an at the counter check in. Online check ins are often at least 24 hours before the flight. Many airlines also allow check ins at a kiosk, and they're open 24h/day.